# Different fundamental matrices computed by findFundamentalMat() and stereoCalibrate()

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Generally, my task is a 3D Reconstruction from stereo camera data. When I prototyped some pipeline I noticed that fundamental matrices F generated by stereoCalibrate() and findFunamentalMat() are different. I used the same image points (generated from findChessboardCorners()). 
I'm a newbie in OpenCV and cannot understand this behavior.

Sample code:

````
    #the first way
    retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
        objpoints0, 
        imgpoints0, 
        imgpoints1, 
        mtx0, 
        dist0, 
        mtx1, 
        dist1,
        (1280,720,), 
        flags=cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS
    )

    print(F)

    Output:
    [[ 4.83577868e-07  5.83166818e-07 -5.60146344e-04]
     [ 2.08363686e-07 -1.32719297e-07 -8.83620557e-04]
     [-8.43696917e-04 -1.00386918e-03  1.00000000e+00]]

    #the second way

    F = cv2.findFundamentalMat(imgpoints0[0], imgpoints1[0])[0]
    print(F)

    Output:
    [[ 2.80224828e-06  9.97067056e-06 -3.16722635e-03]
     [-1.10304087e-05  3.46639853e-06  3.13386495e-03]
     [ 2.01720640e-03 -7.83331653e-03  1.00000000e+00]]
    ```
````

Comment: What happens when you take points in one of your cameras and get the sets of epilines using {cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines} for each fundamental mat? I'd give a try to it and see what happens

Comment: if ```F1``` and ```F2``` are fundamental matrices generated by ```stereoCalibrate``` and ```findFundamentalMat``` correspondingly, the commands ```cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines(imgpoints0[0], 1, F1)``` and ```cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines(imgpoints0[0], 1, F2)``` give different epipolar lines

Comment: Interesting. Are both correct? That is, do both intersect with the feature points in question? If so, my guess is that the F matrix computed the second way is a general form, unconstrained by the type of geometry, while the one from stereo calibration is constrained by the Epipolar geometry equation. I'll check with the opencv docs and a reference like Hartley and Zissermann's "Multiple View Geometry..."

Answer (score 0):

If we follow the opencv documentation they said the fondamental matrix used in the findFundamentalMat "can be estimated using findFundamentalMat or stereoRectify" .

They didn't talk about the fondamental matrix coming from stereoCalibrate and i never seen someone drawing the epipoles coming with the calibration.

When with findFundamentalMat wee only use points wich are on the 2 images, the stereo calibration use the camera calibration with the rotation and translation to make the fondamental matrix.

Full details : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5